# Codeigniter - validation rules for every field in form

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm new to Codeigniter and found my first trouble when validating form. There's validation form library that helps to do it, and it has function to set rules, for example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
```

I can't find in documentation anything about applying required rule to every field in my form (since it's generated dynamicly based on database content)

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: why not generate the validation rules dynamically based on the database content, surely it is just putting the validation rule in a loop?

Comment: Rooney that is a good idea indeed, not the most elegant in terms of my need, and expectation that CI has build in solution for my problem, thanks a lot, gonna give it a try.

Comment: there is no validation rule for an entire form, Rooneyl's idea is the way to go if that's what you need.

Comment: @Malyo if you are going to do this alot in your system I would extend the form_validation library and write a function that will do it for you

Comment: You should post it in answer so i can accept question, thanks for being so helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Rooneyl here's the answer:

CodeIgniter doesn't support setting validation rules through all input fields. Altho it is possible to use set rule inside a loop. Luckily for me, my form was generated from database content, so looping through same table elements made generating rules easier for me.

Hovewer, if form isn't dynamicly generated, we can always loop through post (taken from CI forum):

```
foreach($_POST as $p) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($p, ucfirst($p), 'required|trim');
}
```